# increase font size of em

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am binding html using JS to a page like below.

```
      _strInnerHtml += "<em>" + value.cate_name + " | " + value.city_name + "</em>";
      _strInnerHtml += "<a href='#' class='activity-item-toggle'><i class='fa'></i></a>";
      _strInnerHtml += "<div class='activity-item-detail'>";
      _strInnerHtml += "<em>Address 1 : " + value.dire_address_1 + "</em>";
      _strInnerHtml += "<em>City : " + value.city_name + "</em>";
      _strInnerHtml += "</div>";
      _strInnerHtml += "</div>";
```

I want to increase the `font-size` of the `em`, but not able to.

Here's how I am trying to

```
.activity-item-detail{
         font-size:15px;
         }
```

Comment: is `activity-item-detail` assigned to `em`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect your page with chrome's tools for instance to see what css element gives to `actvity-item-detail` its font size attribute.
Maybe this can work, as it is more precise:

```
.activity-item-detail em {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```